# VC++ Passing Platform::String^ by ref

Tags: visual-c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

What am I missing here? I thought that the ^ was a smart pointer and that I could pass string by ref to a function. What about other hat objects?

```
// calling code
MyClass::GetString(_str1, _str2);
// both strings are nullptr at this point

/* static */ 
MyClass::GetStrings(String^ str1, String^ str2)
{
    // Read from Local Settings
    auto value = localSettings->Values->Lookup(kKey);
    String^ temp = ref new String(value->ToString()->Data());
    str1 = temp;

    // same for str2
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working in the way you thought it would?

Comment: I would like to pass the strings by ref. IF you look at line 1-2, a static function is called on a class with some string parameters to be populage, _str1 and _str2. 

Inside the function GetStrings, the strings are populated and all looks good. When the call returns (line 3), the variables _str1 and _str2 are no longer valid. Why?

Comment: Those two vars are being set to temp, which is living on the stack and being eliminated when the function retursn> What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `T^` is similar to a pointer type; when you have a function with a `T^` parameter (like your `GetStrings` static member function), the hat is passed *by value*, just like a pointer is passed *by value*.

If you want the `String^`'s passed by reference, you need to use references:

```
void MyClass::GetStrings(String^& str1, String^& str2)
```

Note that references are a C++ language feature and are not part of the Windows Runtime type system.  The Windows Runtime type system also does not support in/out by reference parameters; only out parameters are supported.

Therefore, if `MyClass` is a public Windows Runtime reference type and `GetStrings` is a public or protected member function (basically, if `MyClass::GetStrings` appears in metadata and is callable across the Windows Runtime ABI), you need to use pointers:

```
void MyClass::GetStrings(String^* str1, String^* str2)
```

These pointers are out parameters:  you can write to the pointed-to `String^`s but you cannot read from them.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explaination. I was able to use ^& even though this is indeed a public ref class and the method is public. It is static though.

Comment: I am surprised:  I would expect error C3987:  'f':  signature of public member contains native type 'Platform::String^&'.  Are you using the final release of Visual Studio (the RTM)?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I had to use ^& as the parameter type in the function signatures. ^% is part of CLI, but I am using CX. When I used ^% the compiler would complain about it and replace the % with & to move on. Manually changing them to & worked great.